# How to open PDF in Pixelsense application

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, pixelsense

I'm working on an application for Pixelsense using Microsoft surface 2.0 , I wants to open PDF file in my application in scatterview control , so that i can zoom , rotate & move my PDF file . I have followed the process given http://hugeonion.com/2009/04/06/displaying-a-pdf-file-within-a-wpf-application/

In the link i'm able to open PDF file in scatterview but not able to rotate & zoom it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest conmverting your PDF file to an image or images, then using those. It may be that ScatterView doesnt have all the support for embeded activeX controls etc and has better support for images.

Processing PDF files can be done with GhostScript (open source) or commercial PDF components.

Comment: actually i don't wants to convert my pdf file into image , region is that then user can not comment & mail etc. the content of PDF during the reading time.